Example 3.8 Griffiths why charge density is 0
In the example 3.8, when Griffiths is calculating the potential outside the sphere, it uses the
$$ \nabla ^2 V =0 $$
But when u draw a spherical surface with $r=0$ as origin, and want to calculate the $V$ which is on the surface of this sphere, you will have the charged sphere inside the surface and the diff.eq. will not be homogeneous
$$ \nabla ^2 V = -\sigma / \varepsilon $$
I know its possible to choose another surface, but this is the only we have clear boundary conditions for.
Where am I missing?
The example:
An uncharged metal sphere of radius R is placed in an otherwise uniform electric field E = E0 ˆz. The field will push positive charge to the “northern” surface of the sphere, and—symmetrically—negative charge to the “southern” surface (Fig. 3.24). This induced charge, in turn, distorts the field in the neighborhood of the sphere. Find the potential in the region outside the sphere.


Please consider (a) changing the title as it only indicates where you've found an issue and not what your issue is and (b) including the problem from Griffiths as not everyone has this textbook,.

The charge density is zero outside the sphere, and so $\nabla^2V$ is zero outside the sphere. I think you're mixing up the global nature of the integral form of Gauss's Law with the local nature of the differential form. Think of the two sides of $\nabla^2 V = \sigma/\epsilon_0$ as functions of position, in which case $\sigma$ is zero at positions outside the sphere.

@KyleKanos good point, I was in a hurry  thanks!

@march that's the problem! Where does this $$\nabla ^2 V = ...$$ come from? It was initially an integral on a surface to prove gauss's law. I think because gauss's law is correct in every point regardless of where we are and the surface we choose[which i dont know the proof] so is the poisson's equation for V, right?

In the example Griffiths is only solving for the potential in the region external to the sphere, i.e. the "outside", thus justifying the use of Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 \phi=0$. In the region outside the sphere the charge density is indeed zero. Since the sphere is conducting, it is an equipotential surface ($\vec E =0$, at all points on the spherical surface) so that it serves as the Dirichlet boundary condition for the problem.
However, if for example, the spherical surface was a dielectric instead of a conductor then the electric field would not vanish on the surface, and since the charge there would not be zero given the external field, one would need to appeal to the inhomogeneous equation for the problem of finding the field on the surface itself as opposed to the external problem.

So if it was a non conductor sphere and I wanted to calculate potential outside the sphere, I should have to use the inhomogeneous form? (Excuse my English). In the comments bellow the question, @march almost explained the confusion

@Zahra No. If you want to calculate the potential outside the sphere conducting or not, use only the homogeneous form.

@Zahra As march says in their comment, the differential form of Gauss' law is local, thus anywhere the charge density is zero the potential satisfies the homogeneous equation.

Perfecto! Thanks a lot ✨️✨️✨️
